# install4j: No support for 64-bit bundled java 9?

Tags: java, 64-bit, java-9, install4j

I'm unable to bundle 64-bit Java 9 with install4j 6.1.6 for a working installation.

When "Generate 64-bit executables" is checked, the 64-bit Java 9 bundle is not visible. If it's left unchecked, the bundle is included, but installation on the target system (64-bit Win7) produces an error: "Could not use bundled JRE".

In fact, it seems that install4j only supports 32-bit JREs. When the installer without a bundled JRE is run and no Java is found on the target system, it complains about not finding "a suitable 32-bit JRE".

If that's the case, then it's a major problem, since Java 9+ has no 32-bit version at all.

Has anyone run into this problem? What are my options?

Thanks in advance

Sasha

Comment: You know that Java 9 is no longer supported and you need to use Java 11?

Comment: Well, there are multiple issues with moving to Java 11 considering the existing code. Besides, the install4j issue is the same for Java 11 (I tried it). It still doesn't bundle the JRE correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm unable to bundle 64-bit Java 9 with install4j 6.1.6 for a working installation.

install4j 6 does not support Java 9 at all. You have to use install4j 7 or higher. Then you can bundle both 32-bit and 64-bit Java 9+ JREs.

Comment: Thanks, Ingo. I started suspecting it when I came across the corresponding changelog on the install4j site. Will be getting an upgrade.